# Access Token invalidation in DocuSign API

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, digital-signature

I'm looking into DocuSign's eSignature API. Trying out their 0Auth using a demo account (https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/).

In some 0Auth systems, the access token of a given user gets invalidated after requesting another accessToken for the same user. But it seems previous token continues to be valid as long as it hasn't expire.

Is this a behaviour just for the Demo/Sandbox account or it is possible to rely on behaviour for live accounts as well? (Where several access tokens can be used for the same DocuSign user?

Can each of these accessTokens be refreshed with their respective refreshTokens without limitations/problems?

Answer (score 3):

in this regard, Demo and Production behave the same - you can generate multiple valid tokens for the same user.

That said, this is not a good practice - while the Account Server does not currently have throttles related to token generation, it may in the future. A token should be re-used throughout its lifespan - continuously generating unnecessary tokens is not an appropriate workflow.

Comment: Yes you are right. Exploring the options here.